# ETL tool to access snowflake internal stage files?

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform, etl

I'm new to snowflake even for data engineering. for me, I want to perform extract and transformation of snowflake internal staged files. like below,

| name | size | md5 | last_modified |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| sales/auto_ingest/3.csv.gz | 3915392 | b8b6286365965360a2b2ef0b45 | Thu, 25 Aug 2022 10:29:43 GMT |
| sales/auto_ingest/4.csv.gz | 3915392 | 5719ac992cb5c5718c24d13c0 | Thu, 25 Aug 2022 10:30:03 GMT |

and perform extract and transform using any suggested tool and load it into snowflake table. let me know is it possible? or suggest me any tools for accessing snowflake staged files.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot access Snowflake staged files directly, you will need to use either a connector/driver or an application like [SnowSQL](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/user-guide/snowsql.html).

To upload files to Snowflake stage you can use the [PUT](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/sql/put.html) command and to download them from the stage you can use the [GET](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/sql/get.html) command. Both commands can be used from SnowSQL.